# Super-commentary and or index

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, commentaries

Many times, a given seffer has a commentary and or index written on it, but due to lack of knowledge about it or lack of accessibility, the commentary/index remains largely unknown.

This question requests the posting of such commentary/indexes.

The preferred format should be to name the original seffer and author in Hebrew and English, followed by the name of the commentary/index and author in Hebrew and English, along with any helpful information such as the [ISBN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) if applicable, links etc.
Please indicate if it is a commentary, index, or both.

In order to keep this from being ridiculously broad, let's limit the scope.

1. An extremely popular work with many super-commentaries should not be included, even if a particular commentary is completely unknown. So, for example, no commentaries/indexes on the Talmud or Rambam need apply.
2. The super-commentary index should be dedicated to a particular seffer, not a collation of previous works with commentary upon them. So, for example, Mishna Berurah on halacha and Sha'arei Aharon on Torah are disqualified.
3. Works that are considered standard editions of a given seffer, even if they include commentary/indexes. This one may be hard to quantify, but this limitation seems necessary.
   For example a Mossad HaRav Kook edition of a given seffer.
4. A set which was reprinted or added to, which now includes a commentary/index. For example, The Collected writings of Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch. The ninth volume includes an index for the entire set, but that ninth volume was only put out years later. There are people who own and use the original set, but are unaware of the index in the additional volume.
   Another example, The fifth volume of Michtov Me'Eliyahu, which has an index, was not included in the set originally, afaik.
   I'm not 100% sure about this one. Let's see what the comments bring, I can update the question based on community response.

Comment: Reprinted sets which now include an index should be included in the request for sources. Please upvote if you agree.

Comment: Reprinted sets which now include an index should be disqualified from the request for sources. Please upvote if you agree.

Comment: I wasn't expecting many commentless down votes

Comment: you are right about Michtav MeiEliyahu.

Comment: Does Kovetz Hatosfos and Otzar Hashas count ?

Comment: Should this have one community wiki answer?

Comment: @sam I would say Kovetz yes, otzar no due to #1. I'm open to suggestions to make this question friendlier to the community. I only came up with these limitations so this wouldn't get closed as too broad.

Comment: @רבות I'm not against turning it community. I just assumed there might be more inventive for answers if not, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

תורה תמימה - ברוך עפשטיין
Torah Temimah - Baruch Epstein

Commentary:
משיבת נפש - רב יעקב משה פעלדמאן
Meshivas Nefesh - Rav Yaakov MosheB Feldman

Index:
מפתח לתורה תמימה - ד''ר יצחק מרגלית
Mafteach LiTorah Temimah - Dr. Yitzchok Margolis

Index:
ברכת שלמה - בנימין ריבלין
Birchas Shlomo  - Binyamin Rivlin
(This is a backwards index. It is ordered on the Talmud Bavli and Yerushalmi, and points out where the Torah Temimah discusses a given passage.)

Answer (score 0):

| Sefer Hebrew | Sefer English | Commentary Hebrew | Commentary English |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| אור החיים לרב חיים בן עטר | Or HaChaim from Rav Chaim ben Atar | נר למאור לרב ראובן מרגליות | Ner LaMeor from Rav Reuvein Margolis |

Comment: There is an index for Ohr Hachaim as well by Hillel Kuperman

Comment: There are others on or hachaim